# Update primary email address of contact module through SugarCRM 6.5 REST API v4.1

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I can create a record in 'contacts' table and set primary email by 'email1' field. But when I pass updated email address and try to update that contact with 'set_entry' it does not update the email address.

What is the way to update primary email address of a contact in SugarCRM 6.5 with REST API v4.1

Comment: So what calls have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

First there is a pending issue that prevents this from working since 7.8.

How to do it and how to fix the current suiteCRM version.

- First- Create the Email - This are the parameters you need to send:

Code:

```
$parameters = array(
    'session'         => $session_id, //Session ID
    'module'          => 'EmailAddresses', //Module name
'name_value_list' => array(
    array('name' => 'email_address', 'value' => 'mrbarletta@GOOGLE.com'),
    array('name' => 'email_address_caps', 'value' => 'MRBARLETTA@GOOGLE.COM'),
),
);
```

You will get the Email ID that will be needed to relate it with the Contact

```
$parameters = array(
    'session'         => $session_id, //Session ID
    'module_name'     => 'Contacts', //Module name
    'module_id'       => $contactId, 
    'link_field_name' => 'email_addresses',
    'related_id'     => $emailId, 
    'name_value_list' => array(
        array('name' => 'primary', 'value' => '1'),
    ),
    'deleted'         => '0',
);
```

You should get a response like this:

```
(
    [created] => 1
    [failed] => 0
    [deleted] => 0
)
```

This will not work unless they merge my patch or you do it (not upgrade safe, thats why they have to patch the code) https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/pull/5325